# Como calcular o fatorial de uma lista de inteiros utilizando thread?

Tags: python, thread, multithreading, fatorial

Dado um vetor A de tamanho N com apenas números inteiros positivos, calcule o fatorial de cada um deles e armazene o resultado em um vetor B.

Para calcular o fatorial, utilize a seguinte função:

```
def fatorial(n):
  fat = n
  for i in range(n-1,1,-1):
    fat = fat * i
  return(fat)
```

Os modos de desenvolver seu programa devem ser:

A - Usando o módulo threading com 4 threads;

B - Usando o módulo multiprocessing com 4 processos.

Comecei a fazer dessa maneira aqui mas está dando erros, 3 dias nessa questão e não consigo resolver, alguém me ajuda por favor!

```
import threading

vetorA = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
def fatorial(n):
  fat = n
  for i in range(n-1,1,-1):
    fat = fat * i    
  return(fat)

calc = [fatorial(n) for n in vetorA]
t = threading.Thread(target=fatorial, args=[calc])
t.start()
```

Comment: Siemens, bem vindo ao SOpt. Primeiramente algumas considerações. Seria bom que o título de sua pergunta fizesse referencia direta ao seu problema em sí. O título atual nao tem apelo para que as pessoas te ajudem e nao diz muito sobre seu problema. 
Outra coisa. Você menciona um erro mas nao diz qual é o erro. Edite sua pergunta e poste o log do erro que esta dando.

Answer (score 3):

O seu programa está bem encaminhado - o problema é que, como você pode ver acima, você não se preocupou em juntar de volta os resultados da função - você inicia a thread, e nem tenta pegar o valor de retorno.

Tendo entendido isso, vem a próxima questão - *como* pegar valores de retorno de uma thread? Isso não é tão trivial -  a função `fatorial` é chamada em outra thread, retorna o valor dela lá - e lá o valor se perde - a classe `Thread` do Python não tem uma forma de trazer esse valor de volta para a thread inicial - (isso é, não existe uma chamada do tipo `Thread.result()`.

Daí, se você for na literatura, vai descobrir que a comunicação de dados entre Threads normalmente é feita por objetos chamados de Queues. Em Python, as queues para threading estão em `queue.Queue` na biblioteca padrão.

E uma Queue funciona assim: o código em execução pode inserir um valor na queue de um lado - (no objeto Queue de Python usamos o método `.put`), e em outra thread/função o código que vai usar esse resultado usa o método `.get`.

Ok - temos uma peça do quebra cabeças - mas primeiro: você não quer abrir umathred para cada número da sua lista (embora não seja tecnicamente incorreto, é estranho chamar listas de Python de "vetores" - melhor chamar de listas). Você quer 4 threads - normalmente chamamos de "worker threads" (já que seu programa roda numa "thread principal" que vai coordenar a distribuição do trabalho - e essa é uma quinta thread).

Com as filas fica fácil entender como fazer isso: criamos as 4 threads - e em cada uma a função chamada não é a que calcula o fatorial,e  sim, uma função "gerente" que recebe duas filas: uma de parâmetros de entrada, uma de dados de saída - essa função "gerente" recebe dados da fila de entrada, processa os mesmos na função fatorial, e enfileira de volta os resultados na lista de saída.

Na thread principal, após alimentar a fila que serve de entrada para os "gerentes", você coleta os dados da fila de saída, e monta a lista com os resultados.

Mais dois problemas que você tem que resolver com essa arquitetura: (1) como manter os dados de saída em ordem?? Não á garntia que um númro enviado na posição "1" da fila gere o resultado na posição "1" da saída - as threads  executam coisas fora de ordem. (2) como sinalizar para os workers que o "trabalho acabou" e  podem parar a execução.

(não vou por código agora - talvez eu continue depois - mas veja se entendeu, e tente fazer algo com essas explicações.)

**continuando mais um pedaço** - esse padrão de ter "workers" para trabalhar com threads é bem comum - como esse código fica um pouco trabalhoso, ainda mais quando se quer levar em conta todos os casos possíveis, como por exemplo, capturar possíveis exceções que aconteçam dentro do código na thread, o Python inclui há algum tempo o pacote "[concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)" .
Um objeto do tipo `Executor` nesse pacote faz as vezes de manter as threads, as filas, gerenciar a chamada das funções que fazem os cálculos dentro das threads, *e* retornar o valor das mesmas para a thread controladora - você adiciona tarefas criando objetos do tipo "Future" - e pode chamar depois o  método `.result()` nesses `Future` para obter o valor de retorno da função.

Já que está falando de aprendizado, vale a pena fazer das duas formas - entender, como eu descrevi, que as coisas acontecem, e depois usar o concurrent.futures, que permite a mesma coisa, com tratamento de erros e tudo, com código muito mais simples.

E, quanto a usar processos em vez de threads: as duas abordagens são praticamente as mesmas - para fazer "manualmente", você deve usar o `multiprocessing.Process`  e `multiprocessing.Queue` em vez de `threading.Thread` e  `queue.Queue`. Para a abordagem com `concurrent.futures`, o pacote tem duas formas de criar o `Executor`: a classe `ThreadPoolExecutor` e a classe `ProcessPoolExecutor`, e essa é a única diferença para usar threads ou processos.

**dica do resultado**
Se você passar números muito pequenos, ou poucos números, nem vai ver diferença de performance - computação numérica, mesmo em Python, em CPUs modernas é muito rápida. No entanto, quando conseguir notar a diferença vai ver que apenas a forma com multiplos processo vai ter alguma vantagem - a forma com threads deve ser mais lenta do que o mesmo cálculo usando uma única thread. Para entender o que acontece - e acredito que esse seja o desafio desse exercício, sugiro ler a resposta aqui: